# How to scan multiple pages with webhint?

Tags: npm, webhint

I'm using the tool [Webhint](https://webhint.io/) to scan and analyze my webpage. I created a script command in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "webhint-dev": "hint www.example.com -o webhint-analysis.html"
  }
```

When I execute the command it is scanning and building the analysis succesfully. But the problem is that it is only scanning the main URL 'www.example.com' and no subroutes like 'www.example.com/example'.

I have not found any solution in the documentation.